# HeadlessChrome won't start on Bamboo pipeline

Tags: angular, karma-runner, puppeteer

I'm doing continuous integration for my Angular (8) App.

Locally, whenever I try to run the "build" for the project, it works just fine. But when my pipeline at Atlassian Bamboo tries to build and run the tests, it's unable to start **HeadlessChrome**. I found many similar questions, but not one with my exact problem or a solution.

This is the error I'm getting:

> Cannot start ChromeHeadless
>       error while loading shared libraries: libXcomposite.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

This is my Karma conf:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  const process = require('process');
  process.env.CHROME_BIN = require('puppeteer').executablePath();

  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      ...
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/idm-ui'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: [
          '--no-sandbox',
          '--enable-logging'
        ]
      }
    },
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```

And the command I'm running is `ng test --watch=false`. Also, I have `"puppeteer": "^2.1.1"` in my `package.json`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix it. If someone ever has the same problem, the answer is to install these:

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md#chrome-headless-doesnt-launch